# Using exclamation followed by command in jupyter cell and directly using command in terminal has different result, windows system

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter

I just noticed, in windows 11, running jupyter

We have the command `where pip`

however, we run this command in four different places, has different result.

1 I run inside jupyter notebook's cell:

```
!where pip
```

I got the pip's location.

2 I run using jupyter's terminal:

```
where pip
```

I got empty result

3 I run using windows powershell:

```
where pip
```

still empty result.

4 I run using windows cmd:

```
where pip
```

failed with command not found.

So only the one in jupyter cell gave useful info, while jupyter cell using ! should using some shell, but none of the shell I mentioned has the same result, so what specific shell it is using, if it is using some shell. And why no other terminal in windows system could have same result as it?

Comment: Does `%pip list` work in your notebook? You should not be using exclamation point with pip in modern Jupyter. The magic install commands were added in 2019 to overcome deficiencies if using the exclamation point with install commands. Because of using automagics when there is no symbol, then usually without a symbol, magic variations of commands are used. **Usually**. And it is important that this references all modern things. You don't say how recent your versions are? Plus, Windows without Anaconda or some more powerful package manager like that doesn't always integrate perfectly with ...

Comment: <continued> Jupyter. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: that is just because of where pip exists.